# Is Karate DSL affected by CVE-2023-38545: severity HIGH

Tags: github, karate

I got the question if Karate is affected by the vulnerability in curl
i saw that there is an new release
which wil fix
CVE-2023-38545: severity HIGH (affects both libcurl and the curl tool)
CVE-2023-38546: severity LOW (affects libcurl only, not the tool)

no steps top reproduces

Comment: I think you'd get better-informed answers if you were to direct this question directly to the developers of the karate package.

Comment: Even if you got an answer here, would you trust it?

Answer (score 0):

No, Karate is Java based and has no connection to cURL. You can refer to the project directly for security related questions / discovery: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/security